# For each loop in PHP erroring out "invalid argument supplied"

Tags: php

I'm trying to get this function to work but for some reason it errors out on the foreach line saying there is an invalid argument.

```
$scores= TESTAPI::GUL($user->ID);
if (empty($scores)) {
    echo "<p>No Scores</p>";
} else {
    foreach ($scores as $score) {
        echo "<p>".$score."</p>";
    }
}
```

The error I get is: `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Add `var_dump($scores);` before the foreach line. What is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scores = TESTAPI::GUL($user->ID);

if (is_array($scores) && count($scores)) {
    foreach ($scores as $score) {
        echo "<p>".$score."</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>No Scores</p>";
}
```

Comment: I did the following using similar to what you put and it works perfectly: `if(!is_array($scores) && !count($scores)){`

Comment: Be careful, expression `(!is_array($scores) && !count($scores))` will also be true if `$scores=false`, so you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Perfectly fine answer. I'd just like to add that `&& count($scores)` can safely be removed - if it's an empty array, the loop will not be entered anyways.

Answer (score 2):

For example, `empty('')` would also be `true`.

I would recommend to check `is_array($scores) && count($scores)` instead of `empty()`, to make sure the api returned useable output (an array) and that this contains elements (`count() > 0` which is true).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `$scores` is neither an array nor an object...

Comment: Can you provide some additional context such as documentation to support this theory?

Comment: Here you are https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/bc5811f361ead53a803046b128a64d15aba2f2e5/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L5788

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
 foreach ((array) $scores as $score) { ...
```

Comment: Just as a general notice: Type casting to an array could have unwanted side effects, e.g. if a value is an object.